# How to render in a specific bit depth?

Tags: web-audio-api, audio-processing, audiocontext

How can `OfflineAudioContext.startRendering()` output an `AudioBuffer` that contains the bit depth of my choice (16 bits or 24 bits)? I know that I can set the sample rate of the output easily with `AudioContext.sampleRate`, but how do I set the bit depth?

My understanding of audio processing is pretty limited, so perhaps it's not as easy as I think it is.

**Edit #1:**

Actually, `AudioContext.sampleRate` is readonly, so if you have an idea on how to set the sample rate of the output, that would be great too.

**Edit #2:**

I guess the sample rate is inserted after the number of channels in the encoded WAV (in the `DataView`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this directly because WebAudio only works with floating-point values.  You'll have to do this yourself.  Basically take the output from the offline context and multiply every sample by 32768 (16-bit) or 8388608 (24-bit) and round to an integer.  This assumes that the output from the context lies within the range of -1 to 1.  If not, you'll have to do additional scaling.  And finally, you might want to divide the final result by 32768 (8388608) to get floating-point numbers back.  That depends on what the final application is.

For Edit #1, the answer is that when you construct the `OfflineAudioContext`, you have to specify the sample rate.  Set that to the rate you want.  Not sure what `AudioContext.sampleRate` has to do with this.

For Edit #2, there's not enough information to answer since you don't say what `DataView` is.

Comment: Ok ok thanks. So I multiply each value of `audioBuffer.getChannelData(0|1)` by either 32768 or 8388608 and that's it, my final .wav file will have the corresponding bit depth? And I'm not sure I get why I need to divide the final result with 32768 or 8388608...Am I not just going to get back the initial values?

Comment: First, when you create the OfflineAudioContext, you have to specify the sample rate.

Comment: There is currently no support in WebAudio to create a WAV file from an AudioBuffer.  You'll have to find some library to do that for you.  (Or learn to do it yourself.  WAV files are pretty simple.)

Comment: Right, I forgot I actually specified the sample rate at creation. And I know there is no support for wav files creation in the WebAudio API, I use a library called `audiobuffer-to-wav`. Still I don't understand the process you explained to set the bit depth. By "multiply every sample", you mean multiply every value in the `Float32Array` that is returned by `getChannelData`? And why multiply and divide by the same number, is it only something you do when there is scaling involved? Anyway, thanks for the help already.

Comment: Not familiar with that library,but presumably it doesn't do what you want. I no longer really know what you want if you have a library to convert an audiobuffer to a wav file.

Comment: The lib does the basic wav encoding (sets the RIFF information and the other typical WAV headers), but it doesn't allow me to set the bit depth of my choice, which is why I want to understand the process you described in your answer.

Comment: What kind of output does your library produce? Is the resulting WAV file a float32 format?  Is it some 16-bit pcm format?  In other words, how do you know it's not in the format you want? Upload a sample output somewhere for me to look at it.

Comment: The library either gives me the choice to create a Float32 or 16BitPCM wav file. I want to create a 16 or 24 bit wav file, so I gotta do the 24-bit option myself.

Comment: Ok.  Here's part of the solution for a 24-bit wav.  Let `x = buffer.getChannelData(0)[k]`.  Compute `s = Math.floor(x*8388608 + 0.5)` to get a 24-bit (rounded) value.  You'll end up with an array of 24-bit signed integers.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to output this array in the appropriate WAV format; it's not very hard because the format is pretty simple.